# Ordering taxonomy view by date added

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have an taxonomy and an view that displays it.

This view has default sorting by `Taxonomy term: Weight (increasingly)`. I would like to add, as second criteria (when the weights are equal) the date when taxonomy term has been added.

Unfortunately on the list under criteria -> add I cannot see anything date-related:

[image]

Where should I find the date of term has been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [Taxonomy Creation Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_creation_date) module. It adds creation and updated date rows to the database, so you should be able to use it in view.